# What limits amplification of transimpedance amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, photodiode, transimpedance-amplifier

I'm designing a transimpedance amplifier but I'm having trouble getting higher gain. I started with Rf being 16.5 kOhms but then I realized I will need higher gain, so I simply switched it out for 50 kOhm, 100 kOhm, and 1 Mohm, but after the 50 kOhm I stopped getting higher gain.

I basically want to take measurements from a photodiode, and I didn't want to mess around with AC so there is Cf to ensure stability and filter any oscillations. So the main question is is there any limiting factor for the opamp that I'm not seeing?

[image]

Notes:

- Vcc = single supply 3.3V
- Opamp = rail-to-rail MCP617
- Photodiode = sfh 206 k

Comment: Gain at what frequency? What is the application? That's quite a big capacitor there. What type is the capacitor (CF1)?

Comment: It looks like you've got a dual op amp. Why not use the second op amp as another gain stage?

Comment: There's a good reason why op-amp symbols were invented = clarity in your circuit. How did you measure the circuit gain? Please link a data sheet for the op-amp and optical device. What is your required 3 dB frequency?

Comment: Please give more information. What is the output voltage with zero light input and with the intended light input with the different feedback resistors.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, frequvency would ideally be under 1Hz, because I dont need high data rate and I want to avoid problems associated with higer frequvencies. The Cf1 is a MLC cap, and thought is that it would filter out any potential oscilations. And regarding the dual opamp, yes it is, but would be better than just getting Rf1 of higher value?

Comment: And regarding the way i measured it, the output is directly connected to ADC, and I measure every couple seconds.

Comment: And regarding the application, its the sensing circuit for a simple air particle detector that uses IR LED and diffracted light goes to the phodiode.

Comment: And regarding the voltage/current input/output, Im not able to measure the photodiode current as I dont have equipment, so im just testing. And ideally it would be that at dark cca. 0.1V and at max cca. 3.3V.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry I dont know if you get a responce without tag.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry I dont know if you get a responce without tag.

Comment: @AdamHaun sorry I dont know if you get a responce without tag.

Comment: @KevinWhite sorry I dont know if you get a responce without tag.

Comment: In such a system I would always take at least 2 measurements, one without IR LED and one with active LED, and process the difference. This removes all sort of side effects like temperature drift and OpAmp DC offset error. And it allows higher gain in an AC coupled second stage.

Comment: @Jens thank you, im currently taking two measurements and subtracting them. But Im not sure if I understand the AC coupled second stage tho, because the subtracting takes place digitally so its not possible for me to then just amplify the result. But do you think this would be equivalent if i put in high-pass filter and took measurements at about 5kHz?

Comment: @OnHai - It would be useful to put any measurements in the question, not in the comments. How do you know the gain is not what you expect?

Comment: @Kevin White - I understand, well I'm simply monitoring output voltage but at the same lightning conditions for the photodiode I got the same output voltage at 50kOhms and even 3MOhms.

Comment: @OnHai - Put the ACTUAL measurements in the question. Don't just say "the same output voltage". What output voltage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cf is normally pico-Farads.  Assume leakage current through this massive MLCC cap is what is limiting the gain. Replace it with a C0G-class ceramic cap (even 100pF) and the gain will likely improve drastically.

A good analysis of the TIA is [Digikey's Article](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/design-transimpedance-amplifiers-for-precision-opto-sensing) about them.

Comment: Great point. Here are some measurements of MLCC, from them the series resistance of that huge cap could be as low as a few tens of kiloohms. https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an1415-current_leakage_through_ceramic_capacitors.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much I had no idea about this, I will try replacing it :)